# Solving $AX=B$ for partially unknown $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to solve multiple systems of linear equations over $n$ variables $AX=B$, where $B$ is partially unknown. Let us assume that $A$ has shape $n' \times n$, $X$ has shape $n \times m$ and $B$ has shape $n' \times m$.

For example, given equations

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 \\
x_2 & y_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & *
\end{pmatrix},
$$

I am looking for solution spaces

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}, \text{ and} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\alpha
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{for arbitrary } \alpha
\end{align*}

Clearly, I can solve $Ax=b$ repeatedly, by simply dropping those rows which involve unknown right-hand sides (as these constraints are irrelevant). However, this yields time complexity $\mathcal{O}(m \cdot n' \cdot n^2)$ assuming I solve equations using Gaussian elimination.

Is there a faster option?

*If it matters: In my case, the equations are modulo 2.*

Comment: In your example it looks like $x_1=1$, $y_1=x_2=0$ and $y_2=*$.

Comment: Yes, this is one way to see it. However, using stars in general is not very precise. For example, if the solution is $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$, representing the solutions as $(*, *)$ would also include the spurious result $(0, 0)$.

Comment: If you can find solutions for $Ax=\mathbf e_i$ for each $i$, then you can simply cache those and solve $AX=B$ as a sum of solutions for each element of $B$. If the row space of $A$ is not full, things will be more complex.

Comment: @Troposphere Neat idea! Unfortunately, in my case, $A$ is over-determined, so I will not be able to solve all $Ax=e_i$ equations. I was thinking that there might be a generalization of your approach (maybe Gaussian elimination on $(A \mid I)$ or LU-decomposition of $A$), but could not find it...